# Converting multiple Columns of a table into multiple Rows with all other rows repeating

Tags: sql, sql-server, multiple-columns, rows, unpivot

I have something like this

| Id | ddf1 | ddf2 | ddf3 | ddf4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 223 | 112 | 221 | 500 |

I want something like this

| Id | ddfs |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 223 |
| 1 | 112 |
| 1 | 221 |
| 1 | 500 |

I've other columns too in my query. So i want a solution which doesn't effect my other columns.

Comment: what's the cardinality of the other columns you have?

Comment: Please share with us the code you have tried.

Comment: @lemon i've around 37k rows in my code till now

Comment: 37 thousand rows of code, to unpivot 4 columns? That sounds highly inefficient.

Comment: @Larnu im doing data migration which involves many tables through join, it's partitioned. For one partition i need unpivot. Btw issue is now solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do something like this.
See working fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f911aab109ffdd6c6217455b1fc09e75)

```
select id,ddfs
from yourtable t cross apply
(values ('ddf1',t.ddf1),('ddf2',t.ddf2), ('ddf3',t.ddf3) ,('ddf4',t.ddf4)) v(k,ddfs)
```